# django-import-export and efficient large csv upload (bulk_create)

Tags: django, csv, django-import-export

I would like to be able to use django-import-export to import a large csv. However, because of the way this plugin is written, it is super inefficient and calls `save()` after every row. Is there an existing modification or separate plugin that allows for a single call to save all the data at once? Something that utilizes Django's `bulk_create()` ideally.

Comment: Are you asking that output of queryset to be written in csv in a single attempt without saving each row?

Comment: No, this question sis specific to the plugin `django-import-export`. Is there a way to overwrite methods in this plugin to modify the way it is saving records?